# "Total" function for a Boolean expression

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, boolean-computation

I have a very long vector of the form

```
{a1 a2 a3 a4 + b1 b2 b3 b4 + c1 c2 c3 c4 + d1 d2 d3 d4 + e1 e2 e3 e4, 
    a1 a2 a3 a4 + b1 b2 b3 b4 + c1 c2 c3 c4 + d1 d2 d3 d4 + e1 e2 e3 e4, 
    a1 a2 a3 a4 + b1 b2 b3 b4 + c1 c2 c3 c4 + d1 d2 d3 d4 + e1 e2 e3 e4, ...}
```

(here I just repeated the elements for simplicity, but in general, each element is different).
And I want to transform it into a Boolean expression where `Plus->Or` and `Times->And`.

What is the fastest way to do it? At the moment, I use `Replace`, but it's really slow when the expression is bigger. Here the simpler example takes 0.000034 seconds:

```
RepeatedTiming[{a1 a2 a3 a4 + b1 b2 b3 b4 + c1 c2 c3 c4 + d1 d2 d3 d4 + e1 e2 e3 e4, 
           a1 a2 a3 a4 + b1 b2 b3 b4 + c1 c2 c3 c4 + d1 d2 d3 d4 + e1 e2 e3 e4, 
           a1 a2 a3 a4 + b1 b2 b3 b4 + c1 c2 c3 c4 + d1 d2 d3 d4 + e1 e2 e3 e4} /. {Times -> And} /. {Plus -> Or}]
```

Also, is there an equivalent of the `Total` function for Boolean expressions?

Comment: Do you need to evaluate it with actual values? You could use 0 / 1 variables and just check if the expression is >0 or use Boole in that case, as `Times` and `Plus` correspond very well with `And` and `Or` here. The equivalent of Total would be `Or @@ ...` i.e `Total[{a,b,c}]` would be `Or@@{a, b, c}`, but you could also use `AnyTrue[{a, b, c}, Identity]`

Comment: I have to evaluate is the expression is True with a SAT solver later on (mixing it with other boolean expressions)

Comment: Do you mean an external SAT solver or Mathematica's own `SatisfiableQ`?

Comment: Solving satisfiability problems is usually slow. I am puzzled and surprised by your statement that `ReplaceAll` is too slow. Can you explain why it is too slow? Give a concrete example, show why you consider it too slow, and explain why it is reasonable to expect better performance (e.g. because another system is considerably faster).

Comment: Use `/. {Times -> And, Plus -> Or}`, i.e. a single `ReplaceAll` instead of two, for a roughly 2x speedup.

Comment: Using `Replace[..., Infinity, Heads -> True]` gives another small speedup compared to `ReplaceAll`. I am not sure why.

Comment: I use `SatisfiableQ` later but with a more complicated expression. I don't know if there's better performance or if I should expect one. I'm solving a problem that scales with a double factorial, and this is one of the parts that take more time, so I was wondering if I can save some time here.